# Unable to view task information in Lightning as we can view in classic

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, tasks

We facing a Page cannot find error in Lightning view of a Task record. But we can see this task in Classic view. Please find the screen shot provided below.

[image]

The above is the classic view.

[image]

This is what we get when we try to view the same in the lightning.

We access this task from Account-> Activity History(Related list)->the record IEC.

Please advise.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: How are you trying to arrive at the task? What click path do you follow? What does the URL show in the address bar? I suspect this is something that somebody either misconfigured or write code for that was broken. The more information we have, the better we can help you. Please [edit] in as much information as you can find. Thanks!

Comment: @sfdcfox it is accessed from  Account-> Activity History(Related list)->the record IEC.